# Get Checkbox value And set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one array with checkboxes values. For example 2,5,9 .... This is my array:

```
var values = params['Values'];
```

And then I need cycle for all checkboxes with current class and set checkboxes if their value in array.

```
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        $(":checkbox[name=Current][value='values[i]']").prop("checked", "true");
    }
```

But its not working(

Comment: Can you please include why it is "not working"

Comment: I dont know. Nothing heppens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`values[i]` is in a string in your example. Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        $(":checkbox[name=Current][value=" + '\'' + values[i] + "']").prop("checked", "true");
    }
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want.
Try this..

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var value = [1,5,6];
  
  value.forEach(function(item, index){
    var idCB = '.cb'+value[index]; 
    $(idCB).prop('checked','true')
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="cb1" value="cb1">CB1
<input type="checkbox" class="cb2" value="cb2">CB2
<input type="checkbox" class="cb3" value="cb3">CB3
<input type="checkbox" class="cb4" value="cb4">CB4
<input type="checkbox" class="cb5" value="cb5">CB5
<input type="checkbox" class="cb6" value="cb6">CB6
```